# run keyword and return status get stuck before the keyword ends

Tags: robotframework

does anybody observed a fault where the
run keyword and return status get stuck and doesn't return from keyword ?
Its just not closing the keyword....
I was waiting 3 days... (ok it was weekend)

```
<kw name="Run Keyword And Return Status" library="BuiltIn">
<doc>Runs the given keyword with given arguments and returns the status as a Boolean value.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>taut_ssh.SftpClient.File Should Exist</arg>
<arg>${filepath}${filePattern}</arg>
</arguments>
<assign>
<var>${ret}</var>
</assign>
<kw name="File Should Exist" library="taut_ssh.SftpClient">
<doc>Fails if the given `path` does NOT point to an existing file.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>${filepath}${filePattern}</arg>
</arguments>
<msg timestamp="20200229 00:45:28.987" level="FAIL">file "/saps/tmn/GDI.PMAAV167.00.001.tgz" does not exist</msg>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20200229 00:45:28.988" starttime="20200229 00:45:28.984"></status>
</kw>
<msg timestamp="20200229 00:45:28.988" level="INFO">${ret} = False</msg>
<status status="PASS" endtime="20200229 00:45:28.988" starttime="20200229
```

Comment: I don't have this problem. Are you able to reproduce it? Could you share a piece of code and config that is reproducing the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `Run Keyword And Return Status` with a simple built-in keyword such as `Log` or similar? Maybe the keyword you are calling has a bug or too big timeout...

Comment: I've never observed this. If it's getting stuck, it's almost certainly because the keyword you are calling is getting stuck.

Comment: as you can see the called keyword was fine returned and status was set to failed
reproducable from time to time... seems to be an problem if we do have several parallel python tasks running

Comment: sharing code and config is quite complicated. Thats only reproducable on our build server where severl python tasks are running sometimes stacked and this is just one. and there are around 20 parallel executions of the same code and the issue occured only in 1-3 of this parallel tasks